# No JNI_OnLoad found runing pocketsphinxAndroidDemo

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I am build the pocketsphinx and sphinxbase and pocketsphinxDemo as given in the

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2011/05/building-pocketsphinx-on-android/

But when I run the PocketSphinxAndroidDemo on the device it shows the initial screen and blacks off.

on the logcat i get error like:

No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo/lib/libpocketsphinx_jni.so 0x40513c80, skipping init

i have created the directory structure as specified in the link and changed in the recogniser.java too.

Please help.

Comment: are you follow all the steps? They mentioned on the site? The error shows that you have not include the necessary Library file in your project.

Answer (score 1):

Just a small checklist, before proceeding:

1. Did you push the required files into the sdcard from adb shell?
2. Made the necessary changes in the recognisertask.java?
3. Changes made to android manifest file?
4. NDK build? ;)

Comment: ok, good enough..problem still seems to be in configuration of the files at your end. Go through [this tutorial](http://swathiep.blogspot.com/2011/02/offline-speech-recognition-with.html), and inform if the problem persists.

Comment: Check DDMS or cd into you sdcard to check if the folder and file structure is build properly.

Answer (score 0):

> No JNI_OnLoad found in
>   /data/data/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo/lib/libpocketsphinx_jni.so
>   0x40513c80, skipping init

This is not a critical error, it's expected. You can ignore it

> But when I run the PocketSphinxAndroidDemo on the device it shows the
>   initial screen and blacks off.

Most likely you didn't put the files in the proper folder. For more information you need to check pocketsphinx log. It's created on the device in the path

```
/sdcard/Android/data/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx/pocketsphinx.log
```

You can find all the information about issues there.

Comment: below is folder structure i am creating on the device. $ pwd /mnt/sdcard $ cd edu.cmu.pocketsphinx $ ls hmm lm pocketsphinx.log $ ls hmm en_US $ ls lm en_US $ ls hmm/en_US hub4wsj_sc_8k $ ls lm/en_US cmu07a.dic hub4.5000.DMP hub4.5000.dic wsj0vp.5000.DMP is this correct? please provide me the corect method to create the folder structure.

Comment: This path is not correct. You miss Android/data in the path at least. For more details you can check pocketsphinx.log as I wrote above and also you can check the sources where the path is configured.

Comment: I have changed my path as shown below. $ cd - /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx created the folders hmm and lm and pushed data onto them. I have changed the path accordingly in recogniser.java as c.setString("-rawlogdir", "/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx"); for all the lines.

Answer (score 0):

The trick was simple for me:
If you have created the structure and needed files on sdcard **you should unplug device from computer and then run the application**, because in plugged mode the sdcard is inaccessible for apps on phone.